# Laravel Cashier (Stripe) subscribing using the existing customer with token

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I am developing a Laravel application that involves subscription payment. Now I am struggling with subscribing the user with token but using the existing customer. This is the scenario. In my application, user can update their payment/ billing information (basically card). When they update the payment info, they are just adding the card information. Then later, user can make payment or subscribe to whatever they want.

First user will add they payment method or card information. So I create the customer like this.

```
     $user->createAsStripeCustomer($token, array_merge($options, [
        'email' => 'email address',
     ]));
```

So the above method will create the stripe customer for the user along with the card. Then tomorrow, user might want to subscribe to a channel. Laravel Cashier provide the following method to subscribe.

```
$user->newSubscription('subscription-name', 'my-plan')->create($token);
```

Then issue with the above code is that, I have to pass the token again. If I have to pass the token, again, I will have to generate the token again in the Javascript. If I have to generate the token again in the javascript, I will have to ask the user to enter the card information again to get token. So what can I do to get user to subscribe using the existing customer info? How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

One method is whenever you create a stripe customer, add the user to a free subscription plan so that he doesn't have to pay anything until he subscribes. When the user starts subscription we can simply change the subscription plan to the desired plan using the following method:

```
$user->subscription('main')
        ->skipTrial()
        ->swap('provider-plan-id');
```

Another method is whenever we create a stripe customer, ask the user to select a subscription plan and put him on the trial period until he subscribes.